# Anchor in iframe breaks parent page formatting

Tags: html

I have an iframe, inside which I have the following:

```
<body>
<a id="top" target="_self"></a>

...

<a href="#top">[top]</a> ...
```

When the link is clicked, it takes the user to the top of the page in the iframe, but the iframe also seems to pin itself to the top of the parent page.

I tried it without target="_self" but it does the same.

Please can anyone shed some light on this?

thank you

Comment: No able to reproduce that. What browser are you testing with?

Comment: Hi sorry, IE9 trying to be HTML5 compliant. On the parent page I have the iframe position absolute, but when I click the top link inside the iframe, the iframe itself get pinned to the top of the parent page.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by using:

```
<a href="#" onclick="location.href="#top">[top]</a>
```